# Does Base64 encoding speed up the upload time for an image uploaded via mobile to server?

Tags: file-upload, encoding, base64

As per the title I'm trying to upload an image from the mobile to the server and it takes time even though it's compressed. I have applied based64 encoding but I don't feel a significant change in the time. Can someone suggest a better approach in which less bandwidth is consumed? Thank you

Comment: *it's compressed* - Base64 is encoding, but not compression. The base64 encoded string is 33% larger than the content which is encoded, e.g original image 1kB, encoded image 1.33kB

Comment: Yep I'm aware of that, probably I was not clear. I compress the image before coding it to base64

Comment: ok, but what's the net result of compression (- x %) and encoding (+ 33%) then?

Comment: Why BASE64? Are you using a email client? If you can upload a binary, it is better to use a binary file. BASE64 is done to transmit binary files into text protocols, so very inefficient.

Comment: @jps net result is less heavy yet there is no ignificant change in time compared to a simple compression

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi not an email client. Just sending an image from mobile app to server backed (like IG does). I was thinking of using Base64 bacause the search I did pointed me in that direction but it seems like it's not the best solution. What's the catch of going binary? Would that help in the task?